# How to setup multiple builds in jenkins as a checkbox linked?

Tags: jenkins, ant

I have a jenkins pipeline where I am calling one more freestyle project to run an ant build.

I have changed this freestyle project to pass github repo url as parameter.

Now, I want to provide set of repositories as an entry in this parameter so that all those repositories should be shown as checkboxes when user clicked on build and whatever checked, all those repositories should be triggered one by one to the same freestyle project with parameter value changed.

How to implement this?

Answer (score 0):

You can use active choice parameter plugin and configure with check box option.

https://plugins.jenkins.io/uno-choice/

While building the job all the URL's which you have selected will be available in string format and each URL will be separated by ",".

You can use regular expression to separate each URL and conditional statements to trigger the freestyle job from pipeline script.